# How to use rename command with printf

Tags: bash, rename, for, printf

As I was trying to fix the episode numbers of a TV series I toyed with the rename function and trying to pass the return from printf as the rename parameters, but could not do it. I tried just about every combination of

```
for j in $(seq 1 9);
do 
    rename 's/"$( - "`printf "%d" ${j}`" - )"/"$( - "`printf "0%d" ${j}`" - )"/g' *
done
```

that I could think of but nothing seemed to work. I ended up just doing it manually since I was only concerned with 1-9 in this case, so

```
rename 's/- 1 -/- 01 -/g' *
rename 's/- 2 -/- 02 -/g' *
...
```

Can someone point out why the above didn't work for future reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are single quoting the entire expression, so no shell interpolation will happen, and Perl will see the most curious regular expression of `"$( - "`printf "%d" ${j}`" - )"` which is interpolated by Perl into something like

```
% perl -E 'say qq{"$( - "`printf "%d" ${j}`" - )"}'
"42 640 - "`printf "%d" `" - )"
%
```

because you asked Perl to interpolate the `$(` variable which you can read about via `perldoc -v '$('`. Suffice to say, this regular expression will probably not match your files. (And demonstrates one of the several pitfalls of attempting to embed multiple languages into one gloriously complicated string; there is really no need as Perl can do it all.)

A better approach would be to match and adjust what you are interested in, which here appears to be a number enclosed by hypens; assuming there is only one number in the filename simply match on that saving a backreference `([0-9]+)` and use [the Perl `sprintf` function](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlfunc.pod#sprintf-FORMAT,-LIST) to pad those numbers as appropriate (plus the important `/e` flag to treat the right hand side as an expression so `sprintf` actually gets called).

```
% touch "blah - "{1..9}" - blah"
% ls
blah - 1 - blah blah - 3 - blah blah - 5 - blah blah - 7 - blah blah - 9 - blah
blah - 2 - blah blah - 4 - blah blah - 6 - blah blah - 8 - blah
% rename 's/([0-9]+)/sprintf "%02d", $1/e' *
% ls
blah - 01 - blah    blah - 04 - blah    blah - 07 - blah
blah - 02 - blah    blah - 05 - blah    blah - 08 - blah
blah - 03 - blah    blah - 06 - blah    blah - 09 - blah
%
```

If there are numbers elsewhere in the filename, then make the regular expression account for that, perhaps something like

```
% rename 's/- ([0-9]+) -/sprintf "- %d -", $1/e' *
% ls
blah - 1 - blah blah - 3 - blah blah - 5 - blah blah - 7 - blah blah - 9 - blah
blah - 2 - blah blah - 4 - blah blah - 6 - blah blah - 8 - blah
%
```

To use regular expressions in `rename` most effectively, see

- http://perl-begin.org/topics/regular-expressions/
- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html
- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html